# Splitting a Large Text File By Line Information

Tags: logging, automation, text-parsing

I'm having a problem with a way too large Log file - During just one day, the log file can have over 100k events. Currently the file size has reached to over 9,6 Gb. The log file is in a simple one logged event, one line written principle, as seen here;

```
2021-10-08T14:55:23.267+0300    INFO    piecestore  download started    {"Piece ID": "XCW7RYD3QBNHZDKDLESNLW7C3TL2OQ2JCXWKE4BNTMEEHB4VL2VQ", "Satellite ID": "12L9ZFwhzVpuEKMUNUqkaTLGzwY9G24tbiigLiXpmZWKwmcNDDs", "Action": "GET_REPAIR"}
2021-10-08T14:55:23.288+0300    ERROR   piecestore  download failed {"Piece ID": "XCW7RYD3QBNHZDKDLESNLW7C3TL2OQ2JCXWKE4BNTMEEHB4VL2VQ", "Satellite ID": "12L9ZFwhzVpuEKMUNUqkaTLGzwY9G24tbiigLiXpmZWKwmcNDDs", "Action": "GET_REPAIR", "error": "file does not exist", "errorVerbose": "file does not exist\n\tstorj.io/common/rpc/rpcstatus.Wrap:73\n\tstorj.io/storj/storagenode/piecestore.(*Endpoint).Download:534\n\tstorj.io/common/pb.DRPCPiecestoreDescription.Method.func2:228\n\tstorj.io/drpc/drpcmux.(*Mux).HandleRPC:33\n\tstorj.io/common/rpc/rpctracing.(*Handler).HandleRPC:58\n\tstorj.io/drpc/drpcserver.(*Server).handleRPC:104\n\tstorj.io/drpc/drpcserver.(*Server).ServeOne:60\n\tstorj.io/drpc/drpcserver.(*Server).Serve.func2:97\n\tstorj.io/drpc/drpcctx.(*Tracker).track:52"}
2021-10-08T15:02:52.494+0300    INFO    piecestore  upload started  {"Piece ID": "RYDIHEI3RWWDCDYLEYYDP3SDXHCFW37F3VL4427KXYODEZNGDKIQ", "Satellite ID": "12EayRS2V1kEsWESU9QMRseFhdxYxKicsiFmxrsLZHeLUtdps3S", "Action": "PUT", "Available Space": 903141388928}
2021-10-08T15:02:52.508+0300    INFO    piecestore  uploaded    {"Piece ID": "RYDIHEI3RWWDCDYLEYYDP3SDXHCFW37F3VL4427KXYODEZNGDKIQ", "Satellite ID": "12EayRS2V1kEsWESU9QMRseFhdxYxKicsiFmxrsLZHeLUtdps3S", "Action": "PUT", "Size": 1024}
```

What would be the simplest, most efficient way to create a small program / .bat for Windows, that does the following things;

- Can be easily scheduled (even for novice) to run at the first day of every month.
- Creates a folder named after the year found in the log entry.
- Creates a subfolders for every month that the log file contains.
- Divides the log file into smaller pieces by month and Satellite ID, then names the file according to the "Satellite ID".
- Places the smaller files in the folder with the correct year and month, overwriting if necessary.
- Smallest reasonable memory (RAM) requirements, that has a minimal speed impact.

optionally also;

- Renames the original log file (which is constantly in use).

The Date format at the beginning of each line is YYYY-MM-DDTHours:minutes:seconds

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a code-writing service and so I doubt you will find many people willing to give you the answer you seek. I would suggest, however, that you look into using Powershell instead of batch for this task as it has much better support for text parsing.

Comment: Apologies if I sounded like I was just looking for someone to do the whole code for me. What I meant was what is the most efficient way of automating such a task; C#, Python, Java, or is it simplest to just write a Powershell or .bat file for the task.

Comment: No worries, was just hoping to give you a better idea of why you weren't getting many responses. "Most efficient" is a fairly subjective measurement; the correct answer depends a lot on your environment and what tools are available to you. C# would likely process the file most quickly but is also the most complicated. Python would be my personal choice, in part because its native JSON tools would simplify things even further. If you need to stick to built-in Windows tools, I'd go with Powershell.